# Getting the "percentage hash-code" the right way in java

Tags: java

I am trying to generate a random number in Java but in an OBVIOUSLY deterministic way. By that I mean I cant use java.Random even though it is predictable. I need the random value to be a formula of a string.

I am trying to get a random number between 0-1 and I tried it like this

```
double random = (double)(address().toString() + i).hashCode() / (double)(int)Integer.Max;
```

This however ends up almost every time resulting in 0.6333. The issue is the address string ends up always being like "server1" or "server2" or "server3".

Is there a better way to get a random number as a function from this string and a number?

Comment: What does an obviously deterministic random number look like?

Comment: I would hope that for example that "server1" -> 0.113 and "server2" -> 0.84 and "server3" ->0.34 every time. The distribution doesn't need to be perfect but there should be high variance between these results.

Comment: Why cannot you use `Random` seeded with the hashcode of the String? `new Random(address().toString().hashCode()).nextDouble()` ?

Comment: Its for a model checker which looks at execution states. Using java random throws it off.

Comment: How does it throw it off? You will get the same number every time for the same input.

Comment: You can just use `(double) address.toString().hashCode / Integer.MAX_VALUE`... `hashCode()` on string is already designed to be distributed evenly. :) @Thilo are you sure, that seed would work? Then each time you calculate `random` for `server1`, you would get different result. Only the different results would be same across any processes calling Random with same seed.

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek: Of course. This is totally deterministic, even across JDK versions and vendors, as the exact algorithm is part of the spec. Same seed, exact same sequence of random numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better distribution, use `(int) Math.pow(i, i)` instead of `i` in your formula and use `Math::abs` to avoid negative values.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(
                    Math.abs((double) ("Hello" + (int) Math.pow(i, i)).hashCode() / (double) (int) Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0.9951498815767233
0.9951498801797395
0.849646274861715
0.3390345123312597
0.5100578281609611
0.18870856016348514
0.09847050304453378
0.6037361368554347
0.8181958188387546
0.5456916850738655
```

Comment: Any way you could increase the range of those numbers? They seem fairly similar.

Comment: @CalebK - I've updated the answer. I hope, it helps.